# MS Azure - Unable to create an index in AI Search service

Tags: azure-cognitive-search, azure-openai, azure-ai

I am in the Azure Open AI Studio > Chat Playground. My objective is to Add my own data source for analysis using the chat bot. I have created a specific Blob Storage and container in the same subscription and placed my excel file in there which has the data to analyse. When I go to chat playground and select the option 'Add a data source' then I select 'Azure Blob Storage'. Then I fill in the required information which is all accepted but however 'Enter the index name' field is greyed out and when I input rest of the information, it starts to load and gives an error: "Failed to retrieve information about the selected search resource. Please try again later or choose a different resource."
[Add Data Source error screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r6EQo.png)
I understand that I need to create an index, so I go to my Open AI Search service but no matter from where ever I try to create an index or even add a data source I get the following error:
[Create Index Error Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QQJkA.png)
I get the same error when I try to create index from AI Search 'Overview' screen or if I click on 'Indexers' or even if I click on 'Data sources'. I have checked network and firewall settings and it all looks ok to me although I am no expert in that area hence any help would be much appreciated. Thanks, Raja

I want to create an index, but it is not working for some reason. I tried checking network and firewall but cannot find the issue

Answer (score 1):

> There was an error loading the list of indexes.

In my environment, I got the same error:

**Portal:**

[image]

The above error occurs when your search resource networking is disabled, or it is connected with a firewall-specific IP address.

To resolve the issue, you need to enable all networks in your network panel.

**Portal:**

[image]

After selecting all networks, it takes some time to enable. After that, I can see all my indexes.

**Portal:**

[image]

For more information, you can refer to this  [MS-Document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/search-security-overview)  link.